# how to clear checkbox checked status? with vue

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, checked

when i click next button, i want to remove checkbox checked status,
but i don't use vue to remove it.
this is demo code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    id:0, 
    items: [
    {'id':1,'name':'chk-a','options':['a1','b1','c1','d1']},
    {'id':2,'name':'chk-b','options':['a2','b2','c2','d2']},
    {'id':3,'name':'chk-c','options':['a3','b3','c3','d3']},
    {'id':4,'name':'chk-d','options':['a4','b4','c4','d4']},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    next: function (id) {
      if(id<this.items.length){
        this.id++ 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Checkbox</h1>
  <div v-for="item in items[id].options">
    <input type="radio" name="chk" :id="id">
    <label for="two">{{item}}</label>
  </div>
  <button @click="next(id+1)">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have four sections to a form and want the user to select one option from each form. If so, consider having a field `selected_option` or something similar and use `v-model`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    id:0, 
    items: [
    {'id':1,'name':'chk-a','options':['a1','b1','c1','d1'], 'selected_option': ''},
    {'id':2,'name':'chk-b','options':['a2','b2','c2','d2'], 'selected_option': 'c2'},
    {'id':3,'name':'chk-c','options':['a3','b3','c3','d3'], 'selected_option': ''},
    {'id':4,'name':'chk-d','options':['a4','b4','c4','d4'], 'selected_option': ''},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    next: function (id) {
      if(id<this.items.length){
        this.id++ 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Checkbox</h1>
  <div v-for="item in items[id].options">
    <input type="radio" :name="items[id].name" :id="id" v-model="items[id].selected_option" :value="item">
    <label for="two">{{item}}</label>
  </div>
  <button @click="next(id+1)">Next</button>
</div>
```

Note that the above has `'c2'` automatically selected in the second section. This is to show you an example of default values for `v-model` using checkboxes and to show you what the expected data will look like. Retrieving these values later can be done easily by iterating through `items` and pulling out your corresponding `selected_option` values.

Likewise, you can remove the `checked` status by simply setting the value to `''` for any given `selected_option` field.